# X[i] (row of a matrix shows up as a zero x n dimensional data array even though it's clearly 1xn)

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, reshape

This is my 1st post ever, so please be gentle. I am trying to use X[i] (a row of the numpy matrix in my code below) in a matrix multiplication in order to input a cost functional equation for an assignment but it is throwing a dimension mismatch error. According to the error (attached below), [Python thinks that X[i] is shape 3x0.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9F1S.png)

However in reality, if you just print X[i], [clearly it is dimension 3x1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBxyx.png)

This bug has been driving me crazy last 2 days. My code is attached below, can someone take a look at it for me?

```
# Load data set 
df=pd.read_csv("ex2data1.txt",header=None)
X=df.iloc[:,:-1].values
y=df.iloc[:,-1].values   
y=2*y-1 # the original y-values are 0,1 this makes them be -1 or 1. 

pos , neg = (y==1).reshape(100,1) , (y==-1).reshape(100,1)

#Create full X matrix with 1s at end in order to calculate weights 

X0 = np.ones((len(X),1))
X1 = np.hstack((X,X0))

W = y@LA.pinv(X1.transpose())

#cost function

def costFunction1(W, X, y):
    """
    Takes in numpy array W, X and y and returns the corresponding cost function, gradient 
    and hessian  
    """
    
    cost = 0.0
    grad = np.zeros((1,len(y)))
    hess = np.zeros((len(y),len(y)))
    
    for i in range(len(y)):
    
        cost += (1-y[i]*(W@X[i].transpose()))**2
        
        print(X[i])
        
        grad[i] += X[i]@(W.transpose@X[i]-y[i])
        hess[i] += X[i]@X[i].transpose
    
    return cost , grad, hess
```

I tried saving X[i] as its own separate row, tried reshaping it using np.reshape, but nothing worked. Xrow (defined to be X[i]) stayed the same dimension as before.

Answer (score 0):

Following your images and code is a bit confusing, but the `matmul` error involves a 0 dimensional item, not a 3x0 one.

To illustrate:

```
In [135]: x = np.array([1,2,3])    
In [136]: x[0]@x
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [136], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 x[0]@x

ValueError: matmul: Input operand 0 does not have enough dimensions (has 0, gufunc core with signature (n?,k),(k,m?)->(n?,m?) requires 1)

In [137]: x.shape
Out[137]: (3,)    
In [138]: x[0].shape
Out[138]: ()    
In [139]: x[0].ndim
Out[139]: 0
```

`np.dot` is ok with a scalar, but `matmul/@` is not.

```
In [140]: np.dot(x[0],x)
Out[140]: array([1, 2, 3])
```

### edit

With two (3,) arrays

```
In [141]: W=np.array([.2,.3,.4]); xrow=np.array([1,2,3])

In [142]: np.dot(W.transpose(),xrow)
Out[142]: 2.0

In [143]: xrow@np.dot(W.transpose(),xrow)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [143], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 xrow@np.dot(W.transpose(),xrow)

ValueError: matmul: Input operand 1 does not have enough dimensions (has 0, gufunc core with signature (n?,k),(k,m?)->(n?,m?) requires 1)

In [144]: xrow@(W.transpose()@xrow)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [144], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 xrow@(W.transpose()@xrow)

ValueError: matmul: Input operand 1 does not have enough dimensions (has 0, gufunc core with signature (n?,k),(k,m?)->(n?,m?) requires 1)

In [145]: (W.transpose()@xrow)
Out[145]: 2.0

In [146]: _.shape
Out[146]: ()
```

were you intending something like:

```
In [151]: W[:,None]@xrow[None,:]
Out[151]: 
array([[0.2, 0.4, 0.6],
       [0.3, 0.6, 0.9],
       [0.4, 0.8, 1.2]])

In [152]: xrow@(W[:,None]@xrow[None,:])
Out[152]: array([2., 4., 6.])
```

Comment: If I do print(X[i].shape) I get (3,) as my shape instead of appearing as yours does (with () as the dimensions). Something else is happening I think. https://imgur.com/a/gvX9sPL

Comment: `W.transpose()` is still `W`, so the `dot` produces a scalar.